# Jwt Authentication for just web api .net core web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two identities in my app one for admin dashboard (asp.net core mvc) and it uses default authentication by identity class and i have another identity  .Net Core web api for mobile services and i using in this section jwt auth .
How i can use authroize attribute by jwt  for web api controllers only not for all controllers  another controller must use default configuration.
I have this configuration in my startup class :

```
var appSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                    };
                });
```

and for my api controller :

```
[HttpGet("getUsers")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult GetUsers()
        {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different Base Controllers for your MVC Actions and your API Endpoints, and define a different Authentication Scheme for each using an `AuthorizeAttribute`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute

Example:

```
[Authorize(Policy = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public abstract class MvcControllerBase : Controller
{

}

[Authorize(Policy = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{

}
```